# Convert a list of floats to the nearest whole number if greater than x in Python

Tags: python, list, math, int, converters

I'm new to Python and I did my research but didn't get far, hence the post for help.

I have a list of floats which I would like to round to the nearest whole number ONLY if the element is greater than 0.50.

```
list = [54.12,86.22,0.30,0.90,0.80,14.33,0.20]
```

expected outcome:

```
list = [54,86,0.30,1,1,14,0.20]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the python [conditional expression](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions):

```
[round(x) if x > 0.5 else x for x in lst]
```

e.g.:

```
>>> [round(x) if x > 0.5 else x for x in lst] 
[54.0, 86.0, 0.3, 1.0, 1.0, 14.0, 0.2]
```

To get it exactly, we need to construct an `int` from the output of `round`:

```
>>> [int(round(x)) if x > 0.5 else x for x in lst] 
[54, 86, 0.3, 1, 1, 14, 0.2]
```

Comment: Well at first you didn't use the `round` function, that's why I posted my answer. And now we have identical answers :)

Comment: @rantanplan -- Yeah.  I think I was editing as you posted because I didn't notice that OP wanted `round`ing instead of floor behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wayyy to slow by SO standards when it comes to answering and editing. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy replay guys. Would this code also work if the list contained floats which are strings? if that makes sense?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 Yes if you cast them first into floats. `int(round(float(x)))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply rantanplan, i tried that and this is the output: [54, 86, 0, 1, 1, 14, 0] as you can see, index 2 and 6 are incorrect, and way around this? thanks.

Comment: @Boosted_d16 -- I just did `[int(round(float(x))) if float(x) > 0.5 else float(x) for x in lst]` and it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks mgilson, that worked. Now what if the elements below < 0.5 had multiple decimals i.e. 0.2012322, how would I round that to 2 decimal points?

Comment: @Boosted_d16 `round` takes a second argument which is an integer that defines the precision of the decimal digits. e.g. `round(2.4546, 3)` produces `2.455`

Comment: i tired that but I wasnt too sure of the syntax, heres what I did but it didnt work - [int(round(float(x))) if float(x) > 0.5 else round(float(x,2)) for x in list]

Comment: @Boosted_d16 You're passing the parameter `2` to the `float` function and not to `round`.

Comment: I get an error "a float is required" if i do - [int(round(float(x))) if float(x) > 0.5 else round(x,2) for x in list]. Hence I tried round(float(x,2)).

Comment: @Boosted_d16 -- Without having your input list, it's pretty hard to diagnose exactly what is wrong.

Comment: Really sorry for being difficult but im a total noob!               list = [54.12,86.22,0.30455547,0.907566,0.80,14.33,0.20658765]

Comment: `[int(round(float(x))) if float(x) > 0.5 else round(x,2) for x in list]` worked for me without an error on the list you provided.  At this point, I think we've answered your original question.  I would advise you to accept one of these 2 answers and post a continuation question -- Create a very simple script which is self-contained and demonstrates the problem so that we can reproduce it.  If we can reproduce the error, it's likely that we can show you how to fix the problem -- Unfortunately, comments just aren't great for conveying all the information necessary.

Answer (score 3):

```
lst = [54.12,86.22,0.30,0.90,0.80,14.33,0.20]
new_list = [int(round(n)) if n > 0.5 else n for n in lst]
```

Output:

```
In [12]: new_list
Out[12]: [54, 86, 0.3, 1, 1, 14, 0.2]
```

- list is a built in object name and should not be reassigned

Comment: `int(n+.5)` is less readable but 5x faster than `int(round(n))`.  `int(n+(.5, -.5)[n<0])` can be used for positive or negative numbers and is > 3x faster.

Comment: @dansalmo Your faster version is indeed interesting and a worthy note. I am not sure I understood your comment about reassigning built int list though. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @dansalmo nevermind, I just saw your edit. I carelessly copy-pasted the OP's code. Thanks for editing.

Comment: Hey, I noticed the 'In[...] Out[...]' which reminds me of Mathematica. Is there something like Idle for python which has that user interface?

Comment: @GregS I don't know about Mathematica. But if you don't know about `ipython` check it out now! http://ipython.org/