# Pick elements from list and print them in 2-decimal format

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, formatting

I have 2 lists: one for indices (`vv` below) and another for floats (`aa` below). I want to do 2 things with Python 2.7.

(1) use `vv` to pick elements from `aa` to create a new list `ww`

(2) print `ww` in 2-decimal format.
The number of indices varies. I manage to do these with the following code

```
# A list of indices
vv = [1, 2, 4]
# A list of floats
aa = [31.123456, 37.354135, 41.987438, 43.458713, 52.687135, 65.321486]

ww = []
for ii in vv:
    ww.append(aa[ii])

print "Indices ", vv, "correspond to [",
for ff in ww:
    print "%.2f," % ff,

print "]"
```

Its output is:

```
    Indices  [1, 2, 4] correspond to [ 37.35, 41.99, 52.69, ]
```

but I'm not content with this. For (1), is there a more Pythonish way to do that, and for (2), the output does not quite look like as I want it, since there is one too many comma at the end and there are extra spaces around the brackets. It should look like

```
    Indices  [1, 2, 4] correspond to [37.35, 41.99, 52.69]
```

and of course work with any number of indices. Looking for similar posts, they always seem to have a fixed, pre-known number of indices. I guess the [list comprehension](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pShL9DCSIUw)
would do the trick somehow? This was referred to in https://stackoverflow.com/a/16986985/11199684

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` to do that:

```
ww = [round(aa[elem],2) for elem in vv]
print('Indices ' + ','.join(map(str,vv)) + ' correspond to [' + ', '.join(map(str,ww)) + ']')
```

Result:

```
Indices 1,2,4 correspond to [37.35, 41.99, 52.69]
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually after defining `ww` like that it seems to suffice in this example simply ```print "Indices ", vv, "correspond to", ww```
but I'm happy to learn that str/join/map trick.

Answer (score 0):

If python 2.7 or latter than

```
print ("Indices ", vv, "correspond to",[round(aa[x], 2) for x in vv])
```

Try this

Comment: This is close, but not quite yet: the output is `('Indices ', [1, 2, 4], 'correspond to', [37.35, 41.99, 52.69])`

Comment: For that u just need to format your print statement. I just give idea of how to list comprehension.